# Set Id for each EventInput in fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have the following `EventInput`:

```
 calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [
    {
      title: "Event Now - 1",
      start: new Date().setHours(10)
    },
    {
      title: "Event Now - 2",
      start: new Date()
    }
  ];
```

and In HTML:

```
(eventClick)="selectedEvent($event)"
```

Is it possible to set Id for each `EventInput` and get that Id in `selectedEvent` method because I want to get data form Api to show in a modal based on the Id?

```
  selectedEvent($event) {
   // get Id in here ...
    console.log($event.view);
  }
```

[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffk46j) ...

Comment: what is id here ? please make the question more clear

Comment: @Joel Joseph - I read calendarEvents data form Api and Id is related to each EventInput and I want to access that Id in click event;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  selectEvent($event) {
    console.log($event.event.title);
  }
```

You can also set `id` property in the objects,

```
  calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [
    {
      id:1,
      title: "Event Now - 1",
      start: new Date().setHours(10)
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title: "Event Now - 2",
      start: new Date()
    }
  ];
```

and get `id` like this:

```
  selectEvent($event) {
    console.log($event.event.id);
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9ldhs)**